# What does Marty Jr yell while crossing the street in BTTF2?

Tags: dialogue, back-to-the-future-part-2

In *Back to the Future Part II* (1989), at timestamp 23:12, Marty McFly Junior dashes from the Cafe 80’s into the street and is nearly struck by a car.

What does he yell at the driver (specifically what is the final word of his sentence)? My guess below is italicized.

> Don’t drive tranked! Low-res, scuzzball *congro*!

- “Tranked” is in [Futurepedia](https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Trank) as slang for “tranquilized”.
- “Low-res” is in the [same wiki](https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Low-res) as slang for “low resolution” (low quality).
- “Scuzzball” appears in [real-life dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/scuzzball).
- But what’s that last word?

[Futurepedia](https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Hey!_I%27m_walkin%27_here!) has no guess. This [revised draft](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/bttf2_3.pdf) doesn’t have the phrase at all.

Video clip on Yarn: https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/34fd4726-01d3-4f59-8398-fcec3eb7f94f

Comment: Interesting, the subtitles I can find also do not include the last word either.

Comment: Can anyone say why this question would be downvoted? Is it not in the right place, clearly worded, and properly sourced? Thank you.

Comment: Because it really is not important to the movie what the word actually is. Its trivia and so off-topic for this site

Comment: There are many “what does this character say” questions throughout the forum (the “related” column on this page is full of them). I’m disappointed my question was closed, but I’ll leave it at that. I appreciate the chance to dialogue (no pun intended), thank you.

Comment: @Paulie_D - "Trivia" is no longer a closeable reason. This question is also answerable

Comment: @Valorum but it was off topic back in 2021.

Comment: Relevant meta post about this question: [The trivia close reason is no longer valid. Please reopen "What does Marty Jr. yell while crossing the street in BTTF2?"](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4935/1006)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like [scoundrel](https://www.google.com/search?q=scoundrel)

> a man who behaves very badly towards other people, especially by being dishonest